# I ran a script to set up dotfiles and can't undo it

Tags: bash, dotfiles

I ran this script to set up some dotfiles managment:

```
#!/bin/bash
############################
# .make.sh
# This script creates symlinks from the home directory to any desired dotfiles in ~/dotfiles
############################

########## Variables

dir=~/dotfiles                    # dotfiles directory
olddir=~/dotfiles_old             # old dotfiles backup directory
files="bashrc vimrc vim zshrc oh-my-zsh private scrotwm.conf Xresources"    # list of files/folders to symlink in homedir

##########

# create dotfiles_old in homedir
echo -n "Creating $olddir for backup of any existing dotfiles in ~ ..."
mkdir -p $olddir
echo "done"

# change to the dotfiles directory
echo -n "Changing to the $dir directory ..."
cd $dir
echo "done"

# move any existing dotfiles in homedir to dotfiles_old directory, then create symlinks from the homedir to any files in the ~/dotfiles directory specified in $files
for file in $files; do
    echo "Moving any existing dotfiles from ~ to $olddir"
    mv ~/.$file ~/dotfiles_old/
    echo "Creating symlink to $file in home directory."
    ln -s $dir/$file ~/.$file
done

install_zsh () {
# Test to see if zshell is installed.  If it is:
if [ -f /bin/zsh -o -f /usr/bin/zsh ]; then
    # Clone my oh-my-zsh repository from GitHub only if it isn't already present
    if [[ ! -d $dir/oh-my-zsh/ ]]; then
        git clone http://github.com/michaeljsmalley/oh-my-zsh.git
    fi
    # Set the default shell to zsh if it isn't currently set to zsh
    if [[ ! $(echo $SHELL) == $(which zsh) ]]; then
        chsh -s $(which zsh)
    fi
else
    # If zsh isn't installed, get the platform of the current machine
    platform=$(uname);
    # If the platform is Linux, try an apt-get to install zsh and then recurse
    if [[ $platform == 'Linux' ]]; then
        sudo apt-get install zsh
        install_zsh
    # If the platform is OS X, tell the user to install zsh :)
    elif [[ $platform == 'Darwin' ]]; then
        echo "Please install zsh, then re-run this script!"
        exit
    fi
fi
}

install_zsh
```

However it's changed my $ sign on the bash terminal to a % and changed a few other things to.

I was wondering how do I undo this script and revert my bash back to the $ sign, I can't see how to revert everything.

Comment: Please do not give a link. Instead, post a representative and stand alone part of the script.

Comment: do you mean changed for your current session OR changed for all new terminal sessions you startup? (Edit your question to include this info). Good luck.

Comment: a tip: don't run a unknown script without checking what it does...

Comment: Changed all sessions. I edited the post so it's not a link. I honestly thought I knew what I was doing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It installed `zsh` as your default shell instead of `bash`. Run

```
chsh -s $(which bash)
```

(read as «change shell to this shell: which file is bash»)

Comment: I was just typing that :-) +1

Comment: That's brilliant thanks. It's just all these little things you have to pick up...